# MySQL show only the last 8 rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

On my index page I have the "latest work" which shows 8 portfolio pieces 
and I need it to only grab the ones that have active = 1 as well
and I have something like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE active = 1';
```

I tried doing this but its not working and i get errors when I try to pass it in PHPMyAdmin as well.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM portfolio 
        WHERE active = 1 
        WHERE [id] > SELECT
        MAX([id]) - 8 FROM portfolio';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: questions like these have been already answers a million of times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `portfolio` WHERE `active` = 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 8';
```

`ORDER BY id DESC` -> orders rows by highest to lowest value of ID, use ASC for opposite.

`LIMIT 8` -> only 8 first rows

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the most recent 8 active pieces, use LIMIT as well as ORDER BY

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE active=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE active=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8
```